# How can I emulate "typeof (T)" using the System.Linq.Expressions API?

Tags: c#, metaprogramming, expression-trees, cil

I'm trying to create a method that will create a `DataTable` from a list of objects using the `System.Linq.Expressions` API, but I can't figure out how to generate the following IL that I get when I decompile the expression `typeof (int)`.

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldtoken     System.Int32
IL_0006:  call        System.Type.GetTypeFromHandle
IL_000B:  call        LINQPad.Extensions.Dump<Object>
IL_0010:  pop         
IL_0011:  ret
```

Currently I'm trying to skirt the problem by calling `Type.GetType("System.Int")` instead, but I would like to generate the code for `typeof (int)` if at all possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use [`Expression.Constant`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338689(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass in `typeof(int)` as the value:

```
var expression = Expression.Constant(typeof(int), typeof(Type));
```

That's what happens when you use `typeof` within a lambda expression, anyway:

```
Expression<Func<Type>> func = () => typeof(T);
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. I guess I just assumed that it couldn't be that easy.